# How to use "shrinkwrap" constraint with "custom space"?

Tags: constraints, shrinkwrap

How to define the custom space in shrinkwrap constraint?

When I select "custom space" from the list it says what I expect: "transformation relative to custom onject/bone/vertex group".

[image]

[image]

But there is no field where I could specify that custom object/bone/vertex group.
How is it supposed to work?